# Codeception + selenium, automatically closed window causes error

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, codeception

I'm testing a payment process flow using codeception 2.2.9 with webdriver/selenium .

This is the interaction overview:

- user makes his order on our site
- after selecting payment provider, new window is opened with payment providers website in it (this is controlled by payment provider)
- user fills out his payment details on site of payment provider
- the last button click on payment providers website causes the window to be closed (this is where the problem is)
- we get confirmation form payment provider on the background
- user is being taken back to our site

Everything works fine, except when the window gets automatically closed as the last step of the flow by payment provider. I get a warning inside selenium server:

> WARN - Exception: Window not found. The browser window may have been closed.

and an error inside codeception output:

> [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchWindowException]
>   Window not found. The browser window may have been closed.

After payment providers window gets automatically opened I'm switching to it like this:

```
$I->switchToNextTab();
```

The problem is caused by clicking a 'confirm' button on payment providers site which causes the window to get closed automatically like this:

```
$I->click('.form-submitter'); // now the window is gone
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent this error?
Is there a way to expect the window to get closed?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After closing a opened browser window you should command selenium to switch back to the main window. There are several ways to achieve this, simplest is to switch to parent window (http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#switchToWindow):

```
# switch to parent window
$I->switchToWindow();
```

Comment: Thank you, Henri. The problem with this is, that as the window gets automatically closed after clicking the button, the above mentioned error occurs and crashes the test execution. I'm trying to avoid that error / crash of the test. I've made the problem easily reproducible here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624417/codeception-closed-popup-breaks-selemium-test

Comment: For others: the problem got solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624417/codeception-closed-popup-breaks-selemium-test?answertab=votes#tab-top